# Flutter app print statements will not show up in adb logcat

Tags: android, flutter, adb

I am trying to write to adb logcat from my flutter app.

The code I have is as follows. It is just the default init project, with some print writes.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);



  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
        print("HELLOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO");
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("HELLOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO");
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Once I install to my USB debugging device, I run...

```
adb logcat
```

From the terminal. There is lots of logging happening when I do this, but nothing shows up from my flutter application.

When I instead run **flutter run** , then the print statements will show up in the terminal from which I ran it.

Why is nothing showing up in adb logcat?

Comment: Do you have a filtering set up? By priority, for example?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
[Edit: This answer is outdated, check Luciano Ribas's answer for newest solution]
```

**Flutter** use **Run** tab to display logs in **Android Studio** (or **DEBUG CONSOLE** in **VSCode**). That's mean `adb logcat` could not show any thing because it not supported by **Flutter**. More detail [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/cli) and [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/debugging).

However, you could use `flutter logs` instead of `adb logcat` to get your log when you run an apk which installed on your device (debug mode). Sadly, sometime it not work (tested: ~30%).

- Step 1: Run the commend below.

```
$ flutter logs
Showing <device name> logs:
```

- Step 2: Start your application.

```
$ flutter logs
Showing <device name> logs:
I/flutter (<pid>): Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:34710/<secret key>/
I/flutter (<pid>): <your log>
...
```

- Step 3: Read log from command line or start a new command prompt and run `flutter pub global run devtools` after that.

```
$ flutter pub global run devtools
Serving DevTools at http://127.0.0.1:9100
```

- Step 4: Use the `http://127.0.0.1:34710/<secret key>/` link got from command line for start DevTools.

Comment: that is wrong, you can use (here tested with flutter 3.0.2):
'adb logcat | grep flutter'

Comment: It's not wrong, lol. It's outdated. Did you test on the Flutter SDK from Nov 18, 2019 before comment that?

Comment: @TrầnĐứcTâm respects to you for not just editing to the right answer!

Answer (score 4):

Actually in flutter 3.0.2 that works as expected and have the same result as `flutter log`, just execute:

```
adb logcat | grep flutter
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
log('Message******************* $info');
```

You need to import  `import 'dart:developer';`